# ¿Qué falta en este código?

Tags: java

Estoy iniciando a programar en Java y un ejercicio que tengo que resolver es hacer funcionar el siguiente código:

```
// The Players Program:

interface UniversalControl{
   public void play(String media);
   public void stop();
}

 class MobilePhone  extends RadioReceiver implements UniversalControl{
    public void play(){

    }
}
class BluRayPlayer extends DiscPlayer implements UniversalControl{
  public void play(){  


     }
}   

class RadioReceiver{

public RadioReceiver(){    


 }
}

class DiscPlayer{

public DiscPlayer(){  


 }
}       



MobilePhone  objectCel  = new MobilePhone();
BluRayPlayer objectDisc = new BluRayPlayer();

poliPlayer = objectDvd; poliPlayer.play("Frozen"); // Print: viewing the Frozen movie
poliPlayer = objectCd;  poliPlayer.play("Frozen"); // Print: listening to the Frozen song
```

¿Podrían orientarme para resolverlo?

Comment: No se indica ningún esfuerzo de búsqueda/investigación. Favor de consultar [ask].

Comment: "¿Podrían orientarme para resolverlo?", que realiza tu código?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puff a ver, debes leerte un poco más de info, pero entiendo que si empiezas es complejo y a lo mejor eres de las personas que necesitan ver soluciones y a partir de allí puedes continuar, no es lo más óptimo, pero bueno.

Te dejo lo que quieres saber, en los comentarios te doy pinceladas de lo que debes seguir aprendiendo y leyendo.

```
package fips;

// Clases Padre
class RadioReceiver {
    // Es un constructor.
    public RadioReceiver() {
        super();
    }
}

class DiscPlayer {
    // Es un constructor.
    public DiscPlayer() {
        super();
    }
}

// Interfaz
interface UniversalControl {
    public void play(String media);
    public void stop();
}

// Clases que heredan una clase padre e implementan la interfaz.
class MobilePhone extends RadioReceiver implements UniversalControl {
    // Tiene un constructor por defecto.

    // Un método que solo existe en MobilePhone con el mismo nombre,
    // pero lo que hacemos es sobrecarga, la cual solo existe en esta clase.
    public void play() {
        System.out.println("Soy un método, pertenezco a MobilePhone");
    }
    // Métodos que debo de implementar si o si de la interfaz
    // porque todas las signaturas deben tener una implementación.
    public void play(String media) {
        System.out.println("Método play implementado en MobilePhone: "+media);      
    }   
    public void stop() {
        System.out.println("Método stop implementado en MobilePhone");              
    }
}

class BluRayPlayer extends DiscPlayer implements UniversalControl {
    // Tiene un constructor por defecto.

    // Lo mismo, se aplica sobre-carga, esta solo existe en esta clase.
    public void play() {
        System.out.println("Soy un método, pertenezco a BluRayPlayer");
    }
    // Métodos implementados de la interfaz.
    public void play(String media) {
        System.out.println("Método play implementado en BluRayPlayer: "+media);         
    }
    public void stop() {
        System.out.println("Método stop implementado en BluRayPlayer");
    }
}
/**
 * Debe existir una única clase publica, su nombre debe ser
 * igual al del fichero.java, sin ello, no podremos crear objetos
 * de esta clase, pero eso ya te lo estudias y lo entienderás.
 * @author ferpaxecosanxez
 */
public class ClasePrincipal {
    // Necesitas nuestro método de ejecución (main)
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Probando, creamos las clases que heredan e implementan.
        MobilePhone mp = new MobilePhone();
        BluRayPlayer brp = new BluRayPlayer();
        // Probamos los métodos sobrecargados que solo pertenecen a las clases en sí.
        mp.play();
        brp.play();
        // Probando lo métodos implementados.
        mp.play("Media para MobilePhone");
        brp.play("Media para BluRayPlayer");
        mp.stop();
        brp.stop();
    }   
}
```

La salida en consola es:

```
Soy un método, pertenezco a MobilePhone
Soy un método, pertenezco a BluRayPlayer
Método play implementado en MobilePhone: Media para MobilePhone
Método play implementado en BluRayPlayer: Media para BluRayPlayer
Método stop implementado en MobilePhone
Método stop implementado en BluRayPlayer
```

Ve paso a paso, te he ordenado el código y segun lo vas leyendo, te vas informando en la documentación oficial o en foros de confianza.
Espero que te oriente un poco y ánimos!! =D

Answer (score 1):

Esto hace parte del polimorfismo, uno de los 4 pilares fundamentales de la POO (junto a la herencia, encapsulamiento y abstraccion).

Por favor antes que nada consulta todo lo que puedas acerca de las `interface`, *herencia* y *sobre-escritura*; Entonces toma en cuenta estas pautas que te describo para resolver ese ejercicio:

- **Pro-Tip**: Por organización optima del código separa cada clase e interface en un único archivo aparte.
- En las clases `MobilePhone` y `BluRayPlayer` deben aparecer **todos** los métodos descritos en la `interface`, sin excepción, Java obligara a que se sobre-escriba (`@override`) cada uno de esos métodos especificados, ademas de esto `play()` debe ser capaz de tomar un parámetro `String` para procesar e imprimir el resultado mas adelante.
- Por ultimo la respectiva clase principal donde se instancie a los objetos `MobilePhone` y `BluRayPlayer` llamando a `play("Frozen")`.

Espero haber sido lo mas descriptivo posible. Exitos y abrazo de gol.

Answer (score -3):

Dime si te sirve.

```
interface UniversalControl { 
    public void play(String media); 
    public void stop(); 
}

class MobilePhone extends RadioReceiver implements UniversalControl { 
    public void play() {}
    public void stop() {}
} 

class BluRayPlayer extends DiscPlayer implements UniversalControl { 
    public void play() {}
    public void stop() {}
}

class RadioReceiver {
    public RadioReceiver(){} 
}

class DiscPlayer { 
    public DiscPlayer() {} 
}

MobilePhone objectCel = new MobilePhone(); 
BluRayPlayer objectDisc = new BluRayPlayer();

objectDisc.play("Frozen"); // Print: viewing the Frozen movie poliPlayer = objectCd; objectCel.play("Frozen"); // Print: listening to the Frozen song
```

Comment: No se incluye ninguna explicación. Favor de consultar [answer].